# Query to find records without time intersection

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have the following tables :

### tab1

```
for_key1 (key)
val1,
start time 1 (key),
end time 1 (key)
```

### tab2

```
for_key2 (key)
val2
start time 1 (key)
end time 2 (key)
```

Notes :

- key1 and key2 are the foreign keys between the two tables.
- It's guaranteed there aren't two records with the same (key, start time, end time) combination

I would like to produce a query which returns all the records from tab1 which doesn't intersect (in a time perspective) with any record from tab2.

For example :

```
tab1
----
key, val1, start time = 1, end time = 4
key, val2, start time = 6, end time = 10
key, val3, start time = 13, end time = 17

tab2
----
key, val, start time = 5, end time = 8
```

The query will return :

```
key, val1, start time = 1, end time = 4
key, val3, start time = 13, end time = 17
```

Do you have an idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

See this answers [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) on how to determine whether two ranges overlap.

According to the above answer, the below query will give overlapped ranges:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tab1 a
JOIN tab2 b
ON a.start_time <= b.end_time
   AND
   a.end_time >= b.start_time
;
```

Since not overlapped ranges are required, just negate the join condition in the above query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tab1 a
JOIN tab2 b
ON not ( a.start_time <= b.end_time
         AND
         a.end_time >= b.start_time
   )
;
```

In accordance with deMorgan's laws, this can be further simplified into:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tab1 a
JOIN tab2 b
ON a.start_time > b.end_time
   OR
   a.end_time < b.start_time
;
```

See a demo here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d46fc/3

Comment: thanks for the reply. however I don't think it's exactly what I'm looking for. for example, in the attached example, in case tab2 will hold an additional record : key, val, start time = 9, end time = 15 then the third record from the first table will still returned also it shouldn't. the requirement is to retrieve all the records from tab1 that doesn't intersect with any records from tab2